# Showing part of a date in a reaction

Tags: reactjs, date

I want to display my date in yyyy-mm-dd format

He is currently presenting me as follows:

```
 2020-06-29T21:00:00.000Z
```

And I want him to show me:

```
  2020-06-29
```

How to do it in React???

There's something in React like a pipe in Angular??

Answer (score 0):

javascript date objects have some nice functions that may help you.

```js
const d = new Date() // im just declaring a new date, use your method, instead, also be aware of capitalization
const year = d.getFullYear()
const month = d.getMonth() // beware this will output 0 for january, 1 for february...
const date = d.getDate()
console.log(`${year}-${month + 1}-${date}`) // you can check it here
```

check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

The string is ISO 8601 date representation. To convert it into a javascript date object, use

```
new Date('2020-06-29T21:00:00.000Z')
```

To convert this into the desired format, use this

```js
function formatDate(date){
  let myDate = new Date(date);
  return myDate.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+("0" + (myDate.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0" + myDate.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)
}

console.log(formatDate('2020-06-29T21:00:00.000Z'))
```